# Redirect a user after registration when using Devise doesn't work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I am using Rails 4.0.2 and Devise 3.2.2 to handle user registration / authentication.

I need to redirect a user to an an view page immediately after a user signs up for an account. I have try the codes from

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign-up-%28registration%29

but it doesn't work, instead I was redirected to sign in page after I sign up. Pleas see below my codes.

How can I alter devise flow to redirect the user?

Thanks!

**This is my RegistrationsController** :

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  protected

  def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
    'http://www.google.com'   #to test if i was redirect to google
  end
end
```

**This is my routes.rb** :

```
Application::Application.routes.draw do
  get "registrations/update"
  get "pages/home"
  get "pages/privacy"
  get "pages/terms"

 devise_for :users, :controllers => { :registrations => "registrations" }


  root "pages#home"

end
```

Comment: Have you restarted your server?

Comment: Is your new account confirmable and not active yet ?

Comment: Yes I have restarted my server.

Comment: Yes, confirmable and has not been active yet.

Comment: Then you need to define `after_inactive_sign_up_path_for` method, which is just under `after_sign_up_path_for` in the doc you linked.

Comment: Try this, in routes.rb file define after authenticate a user, which page you needs to redirect.   "                          authenticated :users do
    root to: "home#index", as: :any, via: [:post]
  end"

Comment: Ah. I see, so `after_sign_up_path_for` method is unnecessary since the page is for confirmable and inactive users only, right?

Comment: In user.rb file place this code ---> 
protected
def confirmation_required?
  false
end

Comment: put this line before all routes > root "pages#home"

Comment: My user.rb has `devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :confirmable`

Comment: Anyway, I have fix it by adding `def after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
    'http://google.com'
  end ` to my RegistrationsController.  Thanks BroiSatse

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have fix it by adding

```
def after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource) 
   'http://google.com' 
end
```

to my RegistrationsController.

Thanks BroiSatse